# GPS Satellite Settings not available in my android device. HTC ONE 4.4 API 19

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

Hey guys am buiding an android app that makes use of GPS Satellite but my android device does not have any GPS Satellite settings. It only shows turn on/off location and apps that recently requested location. I have tried to traverse all settings but all in vain. Where can I find this settings? or How can I solve this problem?? HTC One android 4.4 api 19. Please help me solve this problem

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Mode option. You will see three options with explanations

- High accuracy
- Battery saving
- Device only (Using GPS only, which you are looking for)

Comment: Thanks @Stallion in HTC it has worked.. On Tecno H6 it only giving me one option [Battery Saving - user wifi and mobile......]... No more option... What about this? What could be the problem? Am grateful for your answer

Comment: These options depends on the devices hardware capability. If hardware is not supporting inbuilt GPS, then those options will not be shown. check the hardware features in the manufacture web site of each device. You can see if it has inbuilt GPS or not

Comment: Thanks very much sir. When I download google maps app it's able to get my location but when I try to access my location using my app it executes Gps disabled code(I have checked this). What is the difference here.? Google maps apps performing without GPS but my app does not...

Comment: even though this is out of topic as per your question, I am posting this link for your reference http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: Here are [some problems of the androidhive GPSTracker code](http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/) explained in detail.

Comment: Thanks guys. My hats off